# Robo3T delete one element inside a key in a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been searching all day to figure out how to do a simple delete for one element inside a document that is inside a collection. I am fairly new to mongo scripts so bear with me.

I am currently using this script to see a certain document:

```
 db.getCollection('roles').deleteOne({"_id": "e9b4afad-cb5c-4588-9560-161867faa5b7"})
```

This is what the document shows in Robo3T after the it is executed:

```
{
    "_id" : "e9b4afad-cb5c-4588-9560-161867faa5b7",
    "appIds" : [ 
        "rpt", 
        "wc", 
        "bw"
    ],
}
```

I am simply wanting to remove "rpt" from appIds. I have tried this so far and it doesn't work:

```
db.getCollection('roles').find({"_id": "e9b4afad-cb5c-4588-9560-161867faa5b7"}).remove({"appIds": "rpt"})
```

Any documentation that'll point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: @whoami Yes it was very helpful and it solved my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an easy task but I believe `$pull` will do the work.

The `$pull` operator removes from an existing array (in a doc) all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

I would try,

```js
db.roles.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { appIds: "rpt"}},
  { multi: true }
)
```

Let me know if it works...

If you want to update a specific id just add it in the first part `{},` -> `{_id: *****},`

See the great documentation of MongoDB at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much.